# Kafka to postgresql using kafka connect jdbc sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to connect kafka with postgresql. I am using JDBC sink connector.

This is my **sink.properties** file:

```
name=test-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=orders
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/casb
auto.create=true
```

I have created a table in postgres named `orders`, next I produce to a topic using:

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \ 
--broker-list localhost:9092 --topic orders \ 
--property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"},{"name":"product", "type": "string"}, {"name":"quantity", "type": "int"}, {"name":"price", "type": "float"}]}'
```

I don't see any row inserted in the table.

**EDIT:**

**Kafka Connect Logs:**

Before sending a message kafka-connect is waiting after printing these logs.

```
[2018-03-12 14:16:55,258] INFO Initializing writer using SQL dialect: PostgreSqlDialect (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:52)
[2018-03-12 14:16:55,260] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=test-sink-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:268)
[2018-03-12 14:16:55,436] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {orders=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:246)
[2018-03-12 14:16:55,553] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {orders=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:246)
[2018-03-12 14:16:57,910] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] Discovered coordinator jojo:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[2018-03-12 14:16:57,913] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] Revoking previously assigned partitions [] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:341)
[2018-03-12 14:16:57,913] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:336)
[2018-03-12 14:16:57,995] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] Successfully joined group with generation 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:341)
[2018-03-12 14:16:57,997] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-test-sink] Setting newly assigned partitions [orders-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:341)
```

After I send a message I get the following Error:

```
[2018-03-12 14:20:59,770] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=test-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:515)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:85)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getValidConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:68)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:56)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2018-03-12 14:20:59,774] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=test-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:517)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:85)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getValidConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:68)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:56)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
    ... 10 more
[2018-03-12 14:20:59,777] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=test-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:173)
[2018-03-12 14:20:59,777] INFO Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:96)
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Check your Connect worker logs (`stdout`) - are there any errors there? What's the status of the connector task? If you have `curl` and `jq` installed you can use this snippet to check (assuming Connect is on localhost, amend if not): `curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors"| jq '.[]'| xargs -I{connector_name} curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/"{connector_name}"/status"| jq -c -M '[.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state]|join(":|:")'| column -s : -t| sed 's/\"//g'| sort`

Comment: I have edited the question to include kafka-connect logs

Comment: @RobinMoffatt How am I assigning the topic to the table? I mean i followed [link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html) and I dont see a table name being mentioned anywhere. So how does the connector know which table to insert data in?

Comment: @el323 JDBC sink to the database to the table name same as the topic name, if the table is not there, it will automatically create that, you can see config here [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html)